# <object> - height attribute not working except for static values

Tags: html, css

I currently have a problem with an `<object>` which looks like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <object id="Object" data="second.html"></object>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #EAEAEA;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border: 3px solid #7f7f7f;
}

#Object {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow : hidden;
}
```

Whatever I do (change second.html text to 1 line or 100) the div stays the same size.

I tried with different percentages and also auto option, the only thing that works is using px which is no option for me (second.html height changes).

Does anyone know why this happens or how to solve this?

**EDIT:** I found something interesting out while trying [Raza Hussain's Tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30059736/object-height-attribute-not-working-except-for-static-values/30060070#30060070)
out:

Text between `<object>` tag behaves normal -> no problem, but if I take same text and write it into second.html (plain text) my problem occurs again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `html` and `body` to `height: 100%` or set a non-percentage-based height.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0; /*Reset Chrome defaults*/
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dyhtvojp/1/

Comment: Your link directs to the `jsfiddle` main page. Perhaps you meant to redirect it to your own fiddle?

Comment: Ah, thanks. Trying to answer too quickly and overlooked that.

Comment: This does not work. object now starts at normal point, but goes that far, that you cant see the end of the box. If trying with completely empty site, so just body>div>object it fills whole screen.

Comment: @VVind0wM4ker I've updated the answer to just fill the viewport.

Comment: @itsjustluck Tried out but still the same.

Comment: @VVind0wM4ker I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Can you try rephrasing your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vh` (viewport height)

`height: 100vh;`

Comment: Same as itsjustluck's answer. It starts normal but goes that far, that you cant see the end of the box. I guess it goes to the end of the site, cause you can't see the end, but theres also no scrollbar,..

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="content">
    <object id="Object" data="second.html">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis lectus metus, at posuere neque. Sed pharetra nibh eget orci convallis at posuere leo convallis. Sed blandit augue vitae augue scelerisque bibendum. Vivamus sit amet libero turpis, non venenatis urna. In blandit, odio convallis suscipit venenatis, ante ipsum cursus augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis lectus metus, at posuere neque. Sed pharetra nibh eget orci convallis at posuere leo convallis. Sed blandit augue vitae augue scelerisque bibendum. Vivamus sit amet libero turpis, non venenatis urna. In blandit, odio convallis suscipit venenatis, ante ipsum cursus augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis lectus metus, at posuere neque. Sed pharetra nibh eget orci convallis at posuere leo convallis. Sed blandit augue vitae augue scelerisque bibendum. Vivamus sit amet libero turpis, non venenatis urna. In blandit, odio convallis suscipit venenatis, ante ipsum cursus augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis lectus metus, at posuere neque. Sed pharetra nibh eget orci convallis at posuere leo convallis. Sed blandit augue vitae augue scelerisque bibendum. Vivamus sit amet libero turpis, non venenatis urna. In blandit, odio convallis suscipit venenatis, ante ipsum cursus augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis lectus metus, at posuere neque. Sed pharetra nibh eget orci convallis at posuere leo convallis. Sed blandit augue vitae augue scelerisque bibendum. Vivamus sit amet libero turpis, non venenatis urna. In blandit, odio convallis suscipit venenatis, ante ipsum cursus augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis lectus metus, at posuere neque. Sed pharetra nibh eget orci convallis at posuere leo convallis. Sed blandit augue vitae augue scelerisque bibendum. Vivamus sit amet libero turpis, non venenatis urna. In blandit, odio convallis suscipit venenatis, ante ipsum cursus augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis lectus metus, at posuere neque. Sed pharetra nibh eget orci convallis at posuere leo convallis. Sed blandit augue vitae augue scelerisque bibendum. Vivamus sit amet libero turpis, non venenatis urna. In blandit, odio convallis suscipit venenatis, ante ipsum cursus augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis lectus metus, at posuere neque. Sed pharetra nibh eget orci convallis at posuere leo convallis. Sed blandit augue vitae augue scelerisque bibendum. Vivamus sit amet libero turpis, non venenatis urna. In blandit, odio convallis suscipit venenatis, ante ipsum cursus augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis lectus metus, at posuere neque. Sed pharetra nibh eget orci convallis at posuere leo convallis. Sed blandit augue vitae augue scelerisque bibendum. Vivamus sit amet libero turpis, non venenatis urna. In blandit, odio convallis suscipit venenatis, ante ipsum cursus augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis lectus metus, at posuere neque. Sed pharetra nibh eget orci convallis at posuere leo convallis. Sed blandit augue vitae augue scelerisque bibendum. Vivamus sit amet libero turpis, non venenatis urna. In blandit, odio convallis suscipit venenatis, ante ipsum cursus augue.</object>
</div>

#content {
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #EAEAEA;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border: 3px solid #7f7f7f;
}
#Object {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


https://jsfiddle.net/joqyo9se/
```

Comment: Thats pretty much the same as i posted, so it does not work (yes i tried). Interesting is, that if you only use text between <object> tags it works. But if i take the whole "Lorem ipsum" text an paste it into the second.html file (nothing else inside, just like a normal text file), div stays at the same size, scrollbar inside the div gets activated and you can scroll through the text.